# How to identify a python statement in a string?

Tags: python

I am doing a project in python with the following requirement:
I have a variable like:

```
some_variable = "os.getcwd()/local/bin"
```

Now there is a python statement "os.getcwd()" in the variable . I have to identify it , execute it and replace the value in the variable.

Note: Any python statement can occur in the string. I have to identify it, separate it and execute and replace the original variable with its value.

In the variable after execution if current working directory is

```
/home/xyz
```

then the variable should contain

```
/home/xyz/local/bin
```

Like `os.getcwd()`, any python statement can occur.
How to identify the python statement in a string?

Comment: The what? You can't do that, almost anything can be a Python statement, since you can name your variables however you like.

Comment: What if `local` and `bin` are variable names? What if you had `foo/bar/baz` and each of those were identifiers referring to float numbers? Suddenly *the whole thing* is a valid Python expression.

Comment: How do you obtain this string in your project? Is it provided by a user or automatically generated by another part of your project?

Comment: Well, he could iterate through every substring, and then try evaluating them. Wouldn't be particularly efficient though (n! time?)

Comment: @BluePeppers That wouldn't work as well, because for example `getcwd` might be a variable but it is a method of `os` as well.

Comment: This is bad design. You should have some "markup" that makes it obvious that the user *wants* the text to be interpreted as Python code. Otherwise, you can fall into traps of unexpected results. For instance, what about `some_variable = "credits"` that could very well be a valid filename.

Comment: There is a *reason* Python grammar uses whitespace, parenthesis and braces to delineate expressions. You'll need to add something to mark  the start and end of expressions in your strings.

Comment: @Mr E: I get the input from xml file like this:<set name="path" eval="os.getcwd()/os.environ['os']/local/bin"/>

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this is generally very hard (for example, because you cannot decide whether an identifier is part of the text or a python name).

Therefore, I'd suggest changing your input a bit (assuming this is possible in your setting): Python template engines usually use some kind of escape sequence to denite the begin and end of a python statement. For [mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), eg., you'd use the string `some_variable = "${os.getcwd()}/local/bin"`, which makes the replacement easy. Additionally, adopting this syntax means that you can just use mako right away and don't have to implement anything yourself.

Of course there are a lot of alternatives to mako, it just was the first one to come to my mind.

Comment: It's not *generally impossible* at all, it's approximately what any language parser does in its early stages.

Comment: python statements come from xml file like:

Comment: `<set name = "xyz" eval = "os.getcwd()/os.environ['os']/bin"/>'

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Well, yes... However, the parser will die on any illegal syntax, while the OP would like to simply ignore it. While impossible might be incorrect, I'd at least consider it very hard.

Comment: @vinaysurve: I you cannot change the XML file's contents to use some kind of delimiters, the approach in my answer won't help you, sorry.

Comment: There are plenty of language parsers which attempt to recover from illegal inputs.  Sure the problem is hard and I agree with the general thrust of your answer and all the comments that OP ought to think more about this problem, but parsing programming languages is an aspect of software engineering that all programmers ought to be at least vaguely familiar with. It would help OP to understand the difficulties in making any progress on this question by understanding what would be required to provide a comprehensive answer.

Comment: True. However, I still do not think that what the OP wants is generally doable because of inherent ambiguity: In the OP's example, `os` is not imported but clearly assumed to be. In `"/sys/fs"`, is `sys` a literal or should one substitute it with `str(sys)` and assume that `sys` should have been imported? Parsers generally handle ambiguity with semantic info (eg. a C++ parser knows whether `a*b` is a multiplication or a declaration by checking whether `a` is a type), but without context (which is missing because of the assumed `import`), I don't think that you can generally solve this problem.